# Is there a proper way to highlight # hashtags and @ users in text?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm studying Rails and trying to write a Twitter-like app.

Is there an easy way to hightlight hashtags starting with `#` and usernames starting with `@`, and make URLs out of them?

I couldn't find a proper gem. Or should I make it my own?

For example: https://twitter.com/Xaput/status/383695262796873728

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More details would be helpful.

you could catch them with regex.

Learn regular expressions. They're worth your time.

http://rubular.com/

http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html#UJ

You didn't tag this with HTML, but that sounds like a large aspect of what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

### Use String#scan

You can use Ruby's [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-scan) method to find all matching expressions within a Tweet. For example:

```
str = 'Foo #bar! Baz @quux. #foobar1'

hashtags = str.scan /#[_\p{Alpha}][\p{Alnum}_]+/
#=> ["#bar", "#foobar1"]

users = str.scan /(?<=[\A\s\\.])@[_\p{Alnum}][^\p{Punct}\p{Blank}]{,14}/
#=> ["@quux"]
```

This will catch the majority of valid usernames and hashtags, but there may be edge cases where the expected results are ambiguous (*i.e.* non-mentions like `\@foo`, or weird-but-valid emails like `foo.@example.com`). In such cases, you will need to adapt the regular expression or perform some additional validation on the results. Your mileage may vary.

### References

- http://www.hashtags.org/platforms/twitter/what-characters-can-a-hashtag-include/
- https://support.twitter.com/articles/101299-why-can-t-i-register-certain-usernames